# ValueError with file extension

Tags: python, bioinformatics, valueerror, scanpy

I downloaded a raw data set from GSE (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE92332) which contains single cell analysis data. There are three different file formats matrix.mtx.gz, barcodes.tsv.gz and genes.tsv.tz

I now tried to run this code in order to load the data:

#Load data

```
data_file = "/Users/---/desktop/single-cell-tutorial/latest_notebook/GSE92332_RAW"
adata = sc.read(data_file, cache=True)
adata = adata.transpose()
adata.X = adata.X.toarray()
```

But I always get the following value error

> ValueError: Reading with filekey
> '/Users/---/desktop/single-cell-tutorial/latest_notebook/GSE92332_RAW/MTX/mtx.gv'
> failed, the inferred filename
> PosixPath('/Users/---/desktop/single-cell-tutorial/latest_notebook/GSE92332_RAW/MTX/mtx.gv.h5ad')
> does not exist. If you intended to provide a filename, either use a
> filename ending on one of the available extensions {'csv', 'data',
> 'tab', 'h5ad', 'anndata', 'h5', 'tsv', 'xlsx', 'loom', 'txt',
> 'mtx.gz', 'soft.gz', 'mtx'} or pass the parameter `ext`.

I understand that I need to add an extension but regardless of whichever extension I add I still get the same error.

I tried all different extensions that are also file types (mtx.gz etc.), made an own folder with only the MTX data and tried calling that but nothing is working.

Comment: Have you tried extracting the files from their compressed formats? .gz and .tz are both compressed file types used in UNIX-based systems

Comment: @Stitt how exactly do I do that? I am very new to coding and learning on the go

Comment: Are you hardcoding literally `/Users/---/`? Why? Like it says, this path does not exist; you can't put files in directories which you don't have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scanpy.read` method is for `.h5ad` files. If loading raw CellRanger MTX, then you should use [the `scanpy.read_10x_mtx` method](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/scanpy.read_10x_mtx.html). E.g.,

```
import scanpy as sc

data_file = "path/to/GSE92332_RAW"
adata = sc.read_10_mtx(data_file, cache=True)
```

As commented, the **.mtx** and **.tsv** files likely need to be unzipped (run `gzip -d *.gz` from command line while in the folder). This is idiosyncratic to `scanpy`, which requires data with `genes.tsv` (pre-v3 CellRanger output) to be unzipped, whereas data with `features.tsv` (v3+ CellRanger output) can stay zipped. At least that's what [the code](https://github.com/scverse/scanpy/blob/ed3b277b2f498e3cab04c9416aaddf97eec8c3e2/scanpy/readwrite.py#L445) shows.

Since this appears to be many runs, you may also need the `prefix` argument to specify which particular run you want to load.